# Firefox searchbar does not work anymore

Tags: firefox

Does anyone have any idea why the search bar of firefox might not work anymore here?
I can type things in,
I can select a search provide,
suggestion during typing in also works,
but if I hit Return, just nothing happens.

If I delete /search.json and restart Firefox, the search works exactly one time before again being non-functional. :-(

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you [start Firefox in safe mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode)?

Comment: Almost. Starting in save mode makes it work the first time without prior deletion of search.json. But also there it just works the first time and then the same behaviour.

Comment: Try [creating a new profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) and see whether you still get the same problem.

Comment: With a fresh profile it works fine, so how to find out what is broken in my profile? I'd prefer fixing my existing profile rather than starting with a new one.

Comment: Are you currently using latest Firefox version, i.e. `29.0.1`? How old is your profile? Which add-ons do you have installed? Post the values of your `browser.search.*` preferences in `about:config`.

Comment: Yes, `29.0.1`. The profile is approximately 2.5 years old I think. I have plenty of add-ons installed, but as the problem reproduces in safe mode those shouldn't make a difference, should they? browser.search.* all show "Standard"